# Uniqueness for second order PDE $-\Delta u = c(u)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider the equation
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = c(u) & \text{ on } \Omega \\
 u = 0 & \text{ on } \partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
The function $c:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies 
$$\sup_{t\in \mathbb R} |c'(t)| \leq \alpha < \lambda_1 (\Omega),$$
where $\lambda_1 (\Omega)$ representes the first eigenvalue of the laplacian in $\Omega$, and $\alpha$ is a constant.

I want to show that this PDE has a unique solution.

Comment: I noticed that my previous proof had a flaw. I adjusted it to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I can show it in the case that $\Omega$ is bounded.

Let $(\lambda_i)$ be the [eigenvalues of the Dirichlet laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue) $L:=-\Delta$ and $(\phi_i)$ its corresponding eigenfunctions $(-\Delta \phi_i=\lambda_i\phi_i)$ which constitute an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Omega)$. It is known by the spectral theorem for compact Hermitian operators that the eigenvalues are positive and have no accumulation points. Thus, we can suppose $0<\lambda_1(\Omega)=:\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2 \leq\dots$.

Suppose $u,v\in H^2(\Omega)$ are solutions of the boundary value problem and let $w:=u-v$. Then $w$ is a solution of
\begin{cases}
L w = c(u)-c(v) & \text{ in } \Omega \\
 w = 0 & \text{ on } \partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
Now write $ c(u)-c(v)$ in terms of the derivative of $c$ using the mean value theorem to get $L w (x)= c'\circ\xi(x) \cdot (u(x)-v(x)) = c'\circ\xi(x) \cdot w(x)$ for some $\xi(x)$ lying between $u(x)$ and $v(x).$

By Parseval's identity,
$$\begin{align}
\Vert w \Vert^2 &=\sum |\langle w,\phi_i\rangle |^2 \\
&=\sum \frac 1 {\lambda_i^2}|\langle w,\lambda_i\phi_i\rangle |^2 \\
&=\sum \frac 1 {\lambda_i^2}|\langle w,L \phi_i\rangle |^2 \\
&=\sum \frac 1 {\lambda_i^2}|\langle L w,\phi_i\rangle |^2 \quad \text{since }L\text{ is self-adjoint,}\\
&=\sum \frac 1 {\lambda_i^2}|\langle (c'\circ\xi ) \cdot w,\phi_i\rangle |^2 \\
&\leq \sum \frac 1 {\lambda_1^2}|\langle (c'\circ\xi) \cdot w,\phi_i\rangle |^2=\left\Vert \frac{c'\circ\xi}{\lambda_1}w\right\Vert^2. 
\end {align}$$

The last norm is finite because $|c'\circ \xi /\lambda_1|$ is bounded above by $ \alpha/\lambda_1<1$ and, thus, doesn't affect the convergence of the integral.

However, if $w$ were not identically $0$ we could say that $$\int \left|\frac{c'\circ\xi}{\lambda_1}w\right|^2\le \int \left|\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_1}w\right|^2 < \int |w|^2,$$
so that  $\Vert w \Vert^2 \leq \left\Vert \frac{c'\circ\xi}{\lambda_1}w\right\Vert^2 < \Vert w \Vert^2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u, v$ be two solutions. Then the function $w = u-v$ solves
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta w + a(x) w = 0 & \text{ in } \Omega\\
w = 0 & \text{ on } \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}$$
where $a(x) = \int_0^1 c'((1-t)v(x)+tu(x)) d t$.
Multiplying the equation by $w$ and integrating by parts, we have
$$\int_{\Omega} |\nabla w|^2 = \int_{\Omega} a(x) w^2.$$
Combined with the variational characterization of $\lambda_1$, the above yields
$$\lambda_1 \int_{\Omega}w^2 \leq \int_{\Omega} |\nabla w|^2 = \int_{\Omega} a(x) w^2 \leq \alpha \int_{\Omega} w^2,$$
where in the last inequality we have used that $\|a\|_{\infty} \leq \|c'\|_{\infty} = \alpha$. Since $\alpha < \lambda_1$, it follows that $\int_{\Omega} w^2 = 0$, hence $w = 0$ in $\Omega$. Equivalently, $u = v$ in $\Omega$, which proves the uniqueness of solutions.